# Find the sum of an arithmetic series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Trying to find the sum of

2 + 3 + 9/2 + 27/4 +.... + (3^20)/(2^19)

My first thought was to convert 2 and 3 to the same format as 3^20/2^19. Came down to that I could write 2 as 3^0/2^(0-1) = 2 and for 3 I could write 3^1/2^(1-1) = 3, etc. I came down to that I could write n as n=21, because I know that the last is 3^20/2^19.

And when I try to use the formula I came down to 21/2 * ((2+3^20)/(2^19))

Would this be the correct answer?

Comment: Are you familiar with geometric series?  Disregarding the first two terms, from the 3rd term on, what is the ratio between the specific term and the previous term?  What is the product of $(1-x) \times (1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots + x^n)$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Here's a [MathJax tutorial]https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to begin with, surround mathematical expressions with `$` signs.  For example, `$2^{30}$` is rendered as $2^{30}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20geometric%20series,previous%20term%20by%201%2F2.) after excluding the first term.

We have $$2 + 3 + \frac{9}{2} + \frac{27}{4} +.... + \frac{3^{20}}{2^{19}}$$
$$=2+3+\frac{3^2}{2^1}+\frac{3^3}{2^2}+....+\frac{3^{20}}{2^{19}}$$
$$=2+\sum_{n=0}^{19}\frac{3^{n+1}}{2^{n}}$$
$$=2+3\sum_{n=0}^{19}\big(\frac{3}{2}\big)^n$$
$$=2+3\frac{\big(\frac{3}{2}\big)^{20}-1}{\frac{3}{2}-1}$$
$$=\frac{10458256051}{524288}.$$